# How to replace multiple columns in a file?

Tags: replace, awk, sed, multiple-columns, solaris

Let's say I have a file  where I want to replace 1st , 3rd and 5th column with AAAA, The file is delimited by `|` (pipe ).

So far I am using a for loop to do that but I think this is consuming a lot of space as I am copying the result after each column replace  to a temporary file  (input file filename is huge)

```
ARRAY=(1,3, 5)

for i in ${ARRAY[@]}
      do

    sed "s/[^|]*/AAAA/$i"  filename  >> /tmp/tempfile

    cp /tmp/tempfile filename
    rm /tmp/tmpfile

     done
```

Please suggest a smarter way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use `awk` for this? It is straight forward:

```
awk -v repl="AAAA" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$1=$3=$5=repl}1' file > new_file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
$ awk -v repl="AAAA" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$1=$3=$5=repl}1' a
AAAA|2|AAAA|4|AAAA|6|7|8
AAAA|2|AAAA|4|AAAA|6|7|8
AAAA|2|AAAA|4|AAAA|6|7|8
AAAA|2|AAAA|4|AAAA|6|7|8
AAAA|2|AAAA|4|AAAA|6|7|8
```

Comment: Hi fedorqui, what does1 stands in the end of  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$1=$3=$5=repl}1' ?

Comment: @user3369871 `1` stands for True. And on True, `awk` performs its default action: print the current line.

Comment: encountered error
awk -v repl="AAAA" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$1=$3=$5=repl}1' a
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @user3369871 are you under Solaris? If so, use the following awk instead --> `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`.

Comment: one more question , if I have to take something as false then should I put 0 in the end , can you give an example to understand your comment better ?

Comment: @user3369871 basic example: `awk '1' file` will print everything from a file. `awk '0' file` won't print anything. In this case, we are saying `awk '{do things} 1' file`, so that `awk` performs the changes and then automatically prints the updated line.

Comment: fedorqui, now I am trying to assign repl and FS from out side like  repl="AAAA"
DEL="1F"
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=DEL} {$1=$3=$5=repl}1' b    but  gives error  Invalid form for variable assignment: BEGIN{FS=OFS=DEL} {$1=$3=$5=repl}1
can you suggest further what I am missing here ? Can't I assign FS and OFS through shell variable ?

Comment: @user3369871 to use bash variables in awk you need to use `-v` --> `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v repl="AAAA" -v del="1F" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=del} {$1=$3=$5=repl}1' file`.

Comment: @user3369871 not sure what you mean here, but probably asking a new question should be better since it seems to be a new, different problem outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I meant like we use -v to use a shell variable in awk similarly how do we use an awk variable in a shell (out side awk but in same script) ?

Comment: @user3369871 using an awk variable once the awk script finished makes no sense. May be best to describe your problem and see how you can do it in another way.

Comment: @user3369871 so what happened?

Answer (score 1):

Generic to several column (set in Col) and pattern replacement (sert in Pat)

```
awk -v 'Col=1,3,5' -v 'Pat=AAAA' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if( ","Col"," ~ ","i",")$i=Pat;print}' YourFile > NewFile
```

Comment: @ NeronLeVelu, sorry I did not understand if( ","Col"," ~ ","i",") completely

Comment: It test if the field index `i` is in the list of column to replace. The original list is completeted with `,` surrounding delimiter to allow to search the pattern *delimiter*  + *value of i* + *delimiter* inside

Comment: its working , when 'Col=1,3,5'  and if( ","Col"," ~ ","i",")but not when 'Col=1 3 5' and  if( " "Col" " ~ " "i" ")

Comment: awk -v Col=1 3 5 -v 'Pat=AAAA' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if( ' 'Col' ' ~ ' 'i' ')$i=Pat;print}' a
input file "5"input file "-v"input file "BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if( "input file "Col"input file " ~ "input file "i"input file ")$i=Pat;print}"

Comment: just try here with space as separator and working fine also (no reason to fail if separator is the same on all part and not with special meaning like `*`)